# Top Tags on Careers Profile don't seem to update in a timely fashion

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, jobs

My account is [ranked #7 overall](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/facebook/topusers) for the [facebook](/questions/tagged/facebook) tag.  However, it won't show up in the top tags on my [careers profile](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/offbysome).  The [#5 rated person](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/sarfraznawaz) for that tag has that tag in the top 10% section on their profile.  In theory that would mean I would at least be in the top 20% since I am only two spots back. It should have updated at least a few weeks ago based on my calculations.

It's not important to me but something I noticed so I figured I would log it for the people that do care.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry about that.  I just finished the fixes for this and they will go out in the morning.

(And kudos for getting to the top of a tag in such short order!)

Comment: hey so seems this is still slow or cached? I know I've been doing better at JQuery and judging from a few other CV's I've seen I should atleast be on the Top 30% for JQuery? Hasn't updated for a few days now.

Comment: I have same problem, my top tag scores are months, if not years old